# Custom SimpleCursorAdapter with imageButton random values

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I am trying to add image button to my custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` for my ListView in my project but I have got one problem with repeating and totally random value of one field.

This is a code of it:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        final Context t = context;
        final Cursor c = cursor;

        ImageButton delimageButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.deletebutton);

        delimageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

               Toast.makeText(t,
                "Delete ID: " + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MyDBAdapter.KEY_ID)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

        if(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBAdapter.KEY_OWNID))>0)
        {   
            TextView own = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ownInfo);
            own.setText("OWN");
        }
        else
        {
            TextView own = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ownInfo);
            own.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I press delimageButton what I get is some random ID of one record (row) of `ListView` that is in current view (I can see it, but it is not the correct id) e.g. if you can see like 5 rows on screen and you press on one of buttons you will get id of other row (one of those 5) but not this one which you pressed (in most of the cases). I remember that there was some trick with this own TextView, but I don't see how it can be putted in here.

So, can you please advice me how can I make it to show correct ID?

I'll be glad for help.

**EDIT**

There is a whole code responsible for setting a ListView together with calling `MyCursorAdapter`:

```
private void refreshList() {
        mySQLiteAdapter = new MyDBAdapter(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.open();
        String[] columns = { MyDBAdapter.KEY_TITLE, MyDBAdapter.KEY_GENRE,
                MyDBAdapter.KEY_OWNID, MyDBAdapter.KEY_ID };
        Cursor contentRead = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllEntries(false, columns,
                null, null, null, null, MyDBAdapter.KEY_TITLE, null);
        startManagingCursor(contentRead);
        Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(contentRead.getCount()));
        MyCursorAdapter adapterCursor = new MyCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.my_row, contentRead, columns, new int[] {
                        R.id.rowTitle, R.id.detail });
        this.setListAdapter(adapterCursor);
        mySQLiteAdapter.close();
    }
```

To clarify, the activity is `ListActivity`.

Comment: How do you know that it isn't the correct id? And what exactly is the question?

Comment: @mango I know, because I am printing it out for tests in layout xml file using SimpleCursorAdapter constructor's values `from[]` and `to`. Thanks for reminding of not asking proper question, I've totally lost it.

Comment: And you see a random id of one record (row) on the `ListView`? But not the one you clicked on, correct? I'm sorry but your post is hard to understand.

Comment: @mango yes, you are correct. I thought it is easy to understand. I will try to rewrite it.

Comment: Have you tried deleting a record off the listview with that same id? To see if it deletes something other than what was clicked?

Comment: @mango I am not sure if I understand correct, but I think yes. I've tried to implement simple function for deleting and it deletes the id that is shown in this toast, not the one I want to (the one that is pressed)

Comment: Well certainly that's perplexing. Can we see the instantiation of the adapter?

Comment: @mango This is all I have right now. Hope you will be able to say what I can do to make this button work correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22215/discussion-between-mango-and-sebap123)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `OnClickListener` is getting the id from the cursor when it is clicked, not when it is constructed. Meanwhile, the listview is changing the cursor position as you scroll around.

I think if you look carefully, you'll find the Toast is displaying the id of the last item that was loaded into view rather than the item that contains the button you clicked.

You can solve this by getting the id when you construct the click listener, like this:

```
delimageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    private int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MyDBAdapter.KEY_ID));
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(t,
            "Delete ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I knew that there was some trick with this. Thank you very much.